# Error when setting listener for Map

Tags: android, google-maps

I would like to set listener for map such as Info Window click or Marker click, but when using setOnInfoWindowClickListener or setOnMarkerClickListener, the app crashes, if I remove the listeners, the app starts normally, anyone help me please, thanks so much!

```
package com.example.mapdemo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;

import com.example.mapdemo.MyLocation.LocationResult;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnInfoWindowClickListener{
    public GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //<cach 2>
        LocationResult locationResult = new LocationResult(){
            @Override
            public void gotLocation(Location location){
                //Got the location!
                mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                        .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
                double dLatitude = location.getLatitude();
                double dLongitude = location.getLongitude();

                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(
                        new LatLng(dLatitude, dLongitude)).title("My Location")
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker_current_location)));
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(dLatitude, dLongitude), 17));
                addMarkers(mMap);
                mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter() {
                    public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {
                        View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_infowindow, null);
                        return v;
                    }
                    public View getInfoContents(Marker arg0) {
                        //View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_infowindow, null);
                        return null;
                    }                   
                });
            }
        };
        MyLocation myLocation = new MyLocation();
        myLocation.getLocation(this, locationResult);

        mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(this);

        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker arg0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),ThemTrangTraiActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void viTriHienTai (View view) {
        LocationResult locationResult = new LocationResult(){
            @Override
            public void gotLocation(Location location){
                //Got the location!
                mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                        .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
                mMap.clear();
                double dLatitude = location.getLatitude();
                double dLongitude = location.getLongitude();
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(
                        new LatLng(dLatitude, dLongitude)).title("My Location")
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker_current_location)));
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(dLatitude, dLongitude), 17));
                addMarkers(mMap);
            }
        };
        MyLocation myLocation = new MyLocation();
        myLocation.getLocation(this, locationResult);
    }

    public void mapType (View view) {
        mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        if (mMap.getMapType() == GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL){
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        } else {
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        }
    }

    public void hienThiTabBarActivity (View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, TabBarActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker arg0) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(getBaseContext(), ThemTrangTraiActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void addMarkers(GoogleMap mMap) {
        //5 do
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(10.79055178, 106.6996908)));
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(10.789337, 106.7000939)));
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(10.7903673, 106.6994548)));
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(10.790025, 106.700367)));
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(10.790910, 106.699948)));
        //5 vang
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(10.789442, 106.698694))
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_YELLOW)));
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(10.789221, 106.698758))
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_YELLOW)));
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(10.789094, 106.699187))
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_YELLOW)));
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(10.788525, 106.699541))
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_YELLOW)));
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(10.788222, 106.699194))
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_YELLOW)));
        //5 xanh la
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(10.789786, 106.701044))
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)));
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(10.789311, 106.700936))
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)));
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(10.788826, 106.700635))
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)));
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(10.788763, 106.701493))
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)));
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(10.788521, 106.701150))
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)));
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/background_light"
            android:onClick="viTriHienTai"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_location_found" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/background_light"
            android:onClick="mapType"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_map" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:onClick="hienThiTabBarActivity" />
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

**LogCat**

```
05-28 11:14:59.722: E/AndroidRuntime(2075): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-28 11:14:59.722: E/AndroidRuntime(2075): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mapdemo/com.example.mapdemo.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-28 11:14:59.722: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
05-28 11:14:59.722: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
05-28 11:14:59.722: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
05-28 11:14:59.722: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
05-28 11:14:59.722: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-28 11:14:59.722: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-28 11:14:59.722: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
05-28 11:14:59.722: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-28 11:14:59.722: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-28 11:14:59.722: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
05-28 11:14:59.722: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
05-28 11:14:59.722: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-28 11:14:59.722: E/AndroidRuntime(2075): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-28 11:14:59.722: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):     at com.example.mapdemo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:66)
05-28 11:14:59.722: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
05-28 11:14:59.722: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
05-28 11:14:59.722: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
05-28 11:14:59.722: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: change your xml and try it with relative or linear layout because in the frame layout should be only a single child.
and try the  Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ThemTrangTraiActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

Comment: What is line 66 in `MainActivity.java`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place map initialize before LocationResult class. This will fix null pointer exception

mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
  LocationResult locationResult = new LocationResult(){}

Comment: Thanks, I got it, could you please explain the reason?

Comment: Reason is simple. your actually trying to set map object only when you got location. The code runs into  mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(this);
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener();  Before getting the location.